# IndexError: list index out of range while trying to find sum of the pair of integer in a list when compared to a target

Tags: python

I am trying to find the pair of integer from the list  when summed up should match with the target. Though it is working fine with the actual target but when i pass any non target for testing i am getting the error

```
arr=[3,4,5,2,1]
target=1
#arr1=sorted(arr)
#print(arr1)

def arrsum(arr,target):
    #arr=sorted(arr)
    i=0
    y=len(arr)
    
   
    if len(arr)<2:
        return -1
    for i in range(y):
        if arr[i]+arr[i+1]==target:
            return i,i+1
        
         
print(arrsum(arr,target))
```

Comment: You can debug this yourself simply by printing the length of the list and then inside the loop print index being used - you’d see the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access the last element then you must take care of the value of `i` which is going out of range. You should run your loop till `(y-1)`, this will give you last element.

```py
for i in range(y - 1):
    if arr[i] + arr[i+1] == target:
        return i,i+1
```

Answer (score 1):

In that case, you need to subtract 1 from `y`

```
for i in range(y-1)
```

Or else, during the last part, the last element would be `arr[i]` but fetching `arr[i+1]` leads to an error

Answer (score 0):

You may do `range(y-1)` because for now ˋarr[i+1]` is out of range for last value

```
def arrsum(arr, target):
    if len(arr) < 2:
        return -1
    for i in range(len(y) - 1):
        if arr[i] + arr[i+1] == target:
            return i,i+1
```